# What is the name of this plugin for the atom text editor?

Tags: plugins, atom-editor

I'm trying to find what is the name of this plugin:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wU9vfiJi-rc
What is the plugin name for the combo text in the editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plugin for the combo text: 
**atom-typing-speedometer**: https://atom.io/packages/atom-typing-speedometer

Comment: that looks different